# Entity Framework WCF IIS issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, iis

I have created a WCF service and hosted in IIS. In my entity framework when using Windows authentication getting exception "underlying provider failed on Open". When it is SQL authentication or incase i pass the user id and password in connectionstring it is working fine. Why this problem persist if i use "integrated security=true". Moreover if service is not hosted in IIS it is working fine.

In my WCF service Entity model is available. I am consuming my wcf service in another web application.

Comment: You should look at stack trace, there might be more descriptive error message. Also, make sure that your app pool account has access to the database.

Comment: How to check app pool have acess to the database

Comment: You can check the app pool the site is using in "Basic Settings..." for the site in IIS. Then look at the the Application Pools node Identity column to find the user for the app pool. How to check whether it has access to the database will depend on which database you are using.

Comment: @AndyNichols In my case my database located in another machine